# Get selected option from dropdown in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails and I was wondering if and how I can get the selected option in a dropdown menu inside a `.erb` file.

At the moment, this is my code:

```
<select name="regions">
    <option value="all">All regions</option>
    <% @regions.each do |region| %>
        <option value="<%= region.name %>"><%= region.name.capitalize %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

The purpose for this dropdown menu is to show a list of regions and to select one that, in future, will act as a filter for a list of displayed items that I will implement as I progress through my learning process.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _"how I can get the selected option in a dropdown menu inside a .erb file"_ - You can't. You can use JavaScript to find the selected option and its value if you need it before submitting the form.

Comment: using javascript you have to set selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit the selection to the rails server, you can make it into a form:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <select name="regions">
    <option value="all">All regions</option>
    <% @regions.each do |region| %>
        <option value="<%= region.name %>"><%= region.name.capitalize %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

From the form you can modify your response with a filtered list.

Otherwise you want to use JavaScript to have purely client-side behaviour.

Comment: @HoratioVelveteen No problem, funny the folk that just tell you to use JS immediately. If you have other issues, first consider if you could choose to do your behaviour server-side rather than client-side. Choose server-side most of the time and use JS only when needed. Have fun learning!